# When I choose the item from selectmenu interaction did not succeed, why? discord py 2.0

Tags: python, discord.py

I created a command that derives "SelectMenu?, but when pressed on any element of this menu then the discord matches me *this interaction failed*. What is the problem?
Code:

```
@commands.command(name='select_menu')
async def select_menu(self, ctx):
    select = Select(
        placeholder='Choose an action...',
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='lbl',
                value='1',
                description='desc'
                ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='lbl',
                value='2',
                description='desc'
                ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='lbl',
                value='3',
                description='Desc'
                )
            ]
        )
    
    async def my_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
        if select.values[0] == '1':
            await interaction.response.reply(f'You chose {select.values[0]}')
        if select.values[0] == '2':
            await interaction.response.reply(f'You chose {select.values[0]}')
        if select.values[0] == '3':
            await interaction.response.reply(f'You chose {select.values[0]}')
    
    select.callback = my_callback
    view = View()
    view.add_item(select)
    
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
    await ctx.send('Select menu', view=view)
```

This code is in the cog

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas, The problem is that there are no mistakes in the console, but the discord itself shows error:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/930193655183056939/1030999896804831313/unknown.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InteractionResponse.reply` doesn't even exist, it's `send_message`. Your linter in your IDE should give you an error about that though.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=response#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message

If you're not getting any errors in your console, you may not have configured logging properly.

Comment: I tried to connect logging, but I do not work for me because I use the function to run the bot: asyncio.run(main()). And the console derives the error:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/939569454390603837/1031136170484174928/unknown.png?size=4096

Code main file:
https://gist.github.com/IndiMops/10c4d460aac834a05474b34ac00359d2

Comment: Your problem is that ``bot.run()`` already calls ``asyncio.run()`` (also ``run`` isnt async so you can't await it). Either use ``start()`` and do logging yourself (see ``utils.setup_logginh``) or remove your asyncio.run. If you want to do async setup stuff, you can use the ``setup_hook`` method instead of needing an asynchronous ``main``. ``run`` will configure logging for you and is not async, ``start`` won't do logging and is async.